# Use a SMC landing page to dynamically generate an image

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, images, landing-page

We want to include a countdown clock within our email. I am looking to reference a SMC landing page from within an image tag like so:

`<img src="http://pages.mail.domain.com/countdown-clock?startDateTime=2016-03-30&saleDurationInHours=24&position=hourTens" />
<img src="http://pages.mail.domain.com/countdown-clock?startDateTime=2016-03-30&saleDurationInHours=24&position=hourOnes" />
<img src="http://pages.mail.domain.com/digit_colon_new.jpg" />
<img src="http://pages.mail.domain.com/countdown-clock?startDateTime=2016-03-30&saleDurationInHours=24&position=minuteTens" />
<img src="http://pages.mail.domain.com/countdown-clock?startDateTime=2016-03-30&saleDurationInHours=24&position=minuteOnes" />`

Where the countdown-clock landing page is calculating the time left on the clock and returning the image content for that time part.

I assume I need to use server-side javascript for this but want to know if and how you can return an image.

Comment: So you want to call the page with some parameters, and then get the correct image back? I have done something very much like this, but that was with php and an external page.

Comment: Should the timer in the mail show the currect countdown time when the mail opens, or should it be the time for when the mail was sent? If its the last, it can be made with AMPscript e.g. SET @Time = NOW()

Comment: I have done this too in PHP, was hoping to keep in within the SMC platform. The reason for using an image call is so that the image is called when the email is opened, rather than when it was processed/sent.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!  Something like this perhaps:

**Landing page**

```
%%[

var @currTime, @endTime, @diffMin, @days, @hours, @min, @dayStr, @hourStr, @minStr
set @currTime = now()
set @dateParameter = QueryParameter("startDateTime")

if not empty(@dateParameter) then

  set @endTime = DateParse(@dateParameter)
  set @diffMin = datediff(@endTime,@currTime, "mi")
  set @days = divide(@diffMin,multiply(24,60))
  set @hours = divide(mod(@diffMin,multiply(24,60)),60)
  set @min = mod(mod(@diffMin,multiply(24,60)),60)

  /* formatting to round down */
  set @days = subtract(@days,mod(@days,1))
  set @hours = subtract(@hours,mod(@hours,1))

  set @dayStr = ""
  for @i = 1 to length(@days) do
    set @dayStr = concat(@dayStr,"<img src='http://placehold.it/30x75?text=",substring(@days,@i,1),"'>")
  next @i

  set @hourStr = ""
  for @i = 1 to length(@hours) do
    set @hourStr = concat(@hourStr, "<img src='http://placehold.it/30x75?text=",substring(@hours,@i,1),"'>")
  next @i

  set @minStr = ""
  for @i = 1 to length(@min) do
    set @minStr = concat(@minStr, "<img src='http://placehold.it/30x75?text=",substring(@min,@i,1),"'>")
  next @i

]%%
  @dateParameter: %%=v(@dateParameter)=%%
  <br>currTime: %%=v(@currtime)=%%
<br>endTime: %%=v(@endTime)=%%
<br>diffMin: %%=v(@diffMin)=%%
<br>days: %%=v(@days)=%%
<br>hours: %%=v(@hours)=%%
<br>min: %%=v(@min)=%%
  <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th align="center">Days</th>
      <th align="center">Hours</th>
      <th align="center">Minutes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">%%=v(@dayStr)=%%</td>
      <td align="center">%%=v(@hourStr)=%%</td>
      <td align="center">%%=v(@minStr)=%%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
%%[ else ]%%
 no date parameter found found
%%[ endif ]%%
```

**Email**

```
%%=TreatAsContent(HttpGet(Concat("http://pages.mail.domain.com?startDateTime=",'2016-03-30')))=%%
```

**Email Output**

[image: sample output]

Comment: Brilliant Adam! As always - though the reason for trying to do this within a landing page via an image load is so it is correct at the time they open it rather than when the email/ampscript is processed on send.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Updated my example to utilize a landing page.  Same basic idea with the AMPScript.

Comment: Hmmm.  After looking at this again, this isn't going to work with a landing page, since the `httpget()` is only evaluated at send time.

Comment: Not sure this is possible since you'd need to dictate the HTTP header content-type.  The choices are limited in SFMC landing pages.  Image types aren't included

Comment: If you want to show the counter when the mail is opened, it must be through the src on the image, as far as I know. With the Httpget() it must be possible somehow to return the correct image url